# Need help taking missing media lists from sound deparment and making them into copy commands

Tags: file, path, grep, copy

I currently work in the motion picture industry and we constantly receive lists of missing media from our sound department. I use a series of commands in TextWrangler in order to remake the lists into useable copy commands to automate the whole process but if I could make this work with one grep command or in some other fashion that would be amazing. Forgive me because my coding skills go about as far as googling what I need and testing things till they work.

Here is an example of a list we get from the sound department:

```
WA6016_03.A01.D114D54EF9A91.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
FRK6030_04A01.D11A054F4C480.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
FRK6029_03A01.D11A054F4C47D.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
FRK6031_02A01.D11A054F4C481.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
FRK6032_06A01.D11A054F4C486.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
FRK6032_04A01.D11A054F4C485.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
FRK6028_02A01.D11A054F4C47B.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
FRK6027_03A01.D11A054F4C47A.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
VI6006_01.A01.D114D54EF9A85.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
R6v0307,Audio Mixdo54FC00E1.wav CX_Jeff_Render_01:OMFI MediaFiles:zJeff_AP:
Bass_Drop_A01.D10BF54E6B931.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zTommy_AP:
Bass_Drop_A02.D10BF54E6B931.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zTommy_AP:
R6v0225_BTA01.D118C54F38E42.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
R6v0225_BTA02.D118C54F38E42.wav CX_Media_06:OMFI MediaFiles:zCassie:
```

And here is how I need it to look:

```
pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/WA6016_03.A01.D114D54EF9A91.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6030_04A01.D11A054F4C480.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6029_03A01.D11A054F4C47D.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6031_02A01.D11A054F4C481.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6032_06A01.D11A054F4C486.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6032_04A01.D11A054F4C485.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6028_02A01.D11A054F4C47B.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6027_03A01.D11A054F4C47A.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/VI6006_01.A01.D114D54EF9A85.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Jeff_Render_01/OMFI MediaFiles/zJeff_AP/R6v0307,Audio Mixdo54FC00E1.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zTommy_AP/Bass_Drop_A01.D10BF54E6B931.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zTommy_AP/Bass_Drop_A02.D10BF54E6B931.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/R6v0225_BTA01.D118C54F38E42.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/R6v0225_BTA02.D118C54F38E42.wav' copied

pause
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. This seemed to work:      awk -F'\t|:' '{sub(/ *$/,x,$1); $NF=$1 q " copied"; $1="pause\ncp " q "/Volumes"}1' q=\' OFS=/ TEST.txt > RESULTS.txt

Answer (score 0):

This looks to do what you want.

```
awk -F: '{
    na=split($1, a, " ")
    printf "pause\ncp \047/Volumes/%s/%s/%s/%s", a[na], $2, $3, a[1]
    for (i=2; i<na; i++) {
        printf " %s", a[i]
    }
    printf "\047 copied\n"
}' inputfile
```

`-F :` to set the field separator to `:`.

`na=split($1, a, " ")` to split the first "field" into the space separated fields we need (and save the count of fields in `na`).

A couple of `printf`s to put it all back together.

This works for single spaces in the file names. Multiple contiguous spaces aren't going to work however.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[ :]' '{printf "pause\n\ncp \047/Volumes/%s/%s %s/%s/%s\047 copied\n\n", $2,$3,$4,$5,$1}' file
pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/WA6016_03.A01.D114D54EF9A91.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6030_04A01.D11A054F4C480.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6029_03A01.D11A054F4C47D.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6031_02A01.D11A054F4C481.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6032_06A01.D11A054F4C486.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6032_04A01.D11A054F4C485.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6028_02A01.D11A054F4C47B.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/FRK6027_03A01.D11A054F4C47A.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/VI6006_01.A01.D114D54EF9A85.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/Mixdo54FC00E1.wav/CX_Jeff_Render_01 OMFI/MediaFiles/R6v0307,Audio' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zTommy_AP/Bass_Drop_A01.D10BF54E6B931.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zTommy_AP/Bass_Drop_A02.D10BF54E6B931.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/R6v0225_BTA01.D118C54F38E42.wav' copied

pause

cp '/Volumes/CX_Media_06/OMFI MediaFiles/zCassie/R6v0225_BTA02.D118C54F38E42.wav' copied
```